# Linked dimension (parent-child) has broken drill-down on analysis

Tags: sql-server, ssas

We have the following scenario:

**OLAP database 1** has a parent-child hierarchy dimension, which is available to perform analysis when browsing its cubes. Everything is fine here.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZAq8.gif]

**OLAP database 2** has another structure, however, the dimension above has been linked here.

We are facing issues when browsing cubes from **OLAP database 2** and drop that dimension for analysis. The drill down performs an awkward behavior. Look:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Gmz.gif]

Am I doing something wrong or this is some weird bug?

Comment: I've made a simple project that reproduces the problem. You only need to run .SQL script and publish the project on Analysis Services (adjusting DS connection strings, of course): http://goo.gl/xSqeLa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whom it may concern, there is an answer on the thread i had opened on Microsoft Connect regarding the issue: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/814167

Basically, this is an unsupported scenario in MOLAP database engine and they closed the ticket as "wont fix". I've managed to clone the broken dimension in order to resolve that and it works like a charm.

Thank you